# How do we use the CakePHP Plugin and get back the auth response array?

Tags: php, cakephp

I note that in OpAuth there is an Auth response array.

https://github.com/opauth/opauth/wiki/Auth-response

I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the same thing using the [CakePHP OpAuth Plugin](https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth)?

Answer (score 0):

The array is already there in the post or get data. There is nothing special to it you could wrap around it.

The page you linked tells you this already. So just use the data from post or get.

> Auth response is usually received by a designated Opauth callback
>   (example) via session, POST or GET.

However, I've written a plugin that is based on the CakeDC users plugin and the CakePHP Opauth plugin to automate a few things https://github.com/burzum/CakePHP-OpauthUsers

Comment: Is there a way to automatically get back the auth response without me guessing whether it is in the session, POST or GET? The context of my question was regards to the CakePHP OpAuth Plugin. But I am also okay to hear more about the OpAuth library in general